# How to save battery power when use a GPS service

Tags: android

I am making an application in which in need to update user location time to time.So i make a service in which i update  user location on every 5 min. My app works perfectly but the problem is it consumes too much battery power.how can i fix it.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
listener = new MyLocationListener();        
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000,200, listener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,     300000, 200, listener);
```

Comment: how are you dispatching your code so that it runs every 5 minutes?

Comment: i am dispatching my code above @pskink

Answer (score 0):

> update user location on every 5 min

Some devices will suck the battery very fast just because GPS receiver (hardware) is on. In such case you not be able to do much as it's not something you can affect. You should check your app on more devices first to ensure the main of yours is not exposing this flaw.

Comment: I am testing my app in 5-7 devices but the response is same.The battery drains very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce power consumption while still getting location updates, use the NETWORK_PROVIDER only. This provider will retrieve the user's current location using trilateration of cellular and Wi-Fi radio signals. However, the downside is that the retrieved location is not as precise, and in rural areas without any cellular or Wi-Fi signals available, you will not get a location at all. You can make a GPS_PROVIDER request in such cases.

Comment: when i only use the NETWORK_PROVIDER  in some device it not works.